# .htaccess folder rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have 3 URLS all pointing to the same site.

- www.abc.co.uk
- www.xyz.com
- www.123abc.org

I have a folder /foo/bar which has lots of sub folders and files in etc. I want to rewrite this to /bar.

So if I have www.abc.co.uk/foo/bar/sheep/page.html I want it to redirect to www.abc.co.uk/bar/sheep/page.html. Is this possible?

Sometime I may have a URL like www.abc.co.uk/foo/bar/foo/page.html so this would become www.abc.co.uk/bar/foo/page.html. Only the first instance of foo would be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You have to use mod_rewite, which I don't know to much about. Maybe this link will help you:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

This should be the first step for achieving it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ $1 [R]
```

Still it has a problem – it will redirect URL "/foo/foo/foo/bar/a.html" to "/bar/a.html" as well.